# need rows with specific column entries in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get the rows which has a specific column value .

is this is correct for it ??

```
 SELECT *
      FROM
        tourDB
      WHERE
        tour_type = insta_deals
```

in this **i want to get all the rows having insta_deals in the column of 'tour_type'.**

Comment: You need to wrap 'insta_deals' with `'`s or `"`s

Comment: Do you want to get all the record who contains `insta_deals` or want to match row whose value is same exact to `insta_deals`

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `" "`

```
SELECT *
      FROM
        tourDB
      WHERE
        tour_type = "insta_deals"
                   ^^^         ^^^
```

Comment: op said `get all the rows having insta_deals in the column of 'tour_type'.` and your solution will select if its equal to that value.

Comment: I interpreted that as "when `tour_type = 'insta_deals'`. It would help if the OP was more specific, so Sumit's answer is correct in that sense

Comment: @Dipesh bro OP used `=` sign, he was just missing `" "`

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM tourDB WHERE tour_type LIKE 'insta_deals'

Answer (score 1):

Without using `'` the value `insta_deals` is understood by mysql as a column name.
So your need to use `'` to specify to mysql that this value is actualy a string.

```
 SELECT *
      FROM
        tourDB
      WHERE
        tour_type = 'insta_deals'
```